# Passing value between IFRAMES and refresh page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I need to pass multiple values between two embedded IFRAMES and refresh the receiving iframe src,
how can this be done. Preferably in c# code behind file (asp.net).

Any ideas will be good.
thanks,

Comment: Is the page and iFrame source page from the same domain?

Comment: i have one parent aspx page containing two IFRAMES from the same domain and i need to pass gui's from one frame to another..

Comment: after receiving the global unique identifier the page should refresh detecting a a change in the value of of the identifier.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/AnywherePlaceHolder.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example using jQuery to sent text to a textbox/input field on a iFrame target page.

**Parent Page with Embedded iFrame:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $iframe1 = $('#iframe1').contents();
        var $iframe2 = $('#iframe2').contents();
        $iframe1.find('#testInput').val('Set on iFrame1');

        $iframe2.find('#testInput').val($iframe1.find('#testInput').val());
    });
</script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="TargetPage.htm" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
        <iframe name="iframe2" id="iframe2" src="TargetPage.htm" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Target Page "TargetPage.htm"**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="testInput" value="" />
</body>
```

**NOTE:** *If your using asp.net, you should use $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>') to access the control using the dynamic ID.*

Comment: this code seems to work but isint this sending values from the parent page to a particular Iframe..also once i receive the value how do i refresh the page

Comment: i need to send values between two embedded ifames

Comment: You can use this same approach to read from iFrame 1 and write to iFrame 2, see updated example above.